docker compose not working after moving docker data directory
I previously had my docker containers mounted on a volume at /data/dockerdata. Now it's mounted (on a new system) at /mydocs/dockerdata. And my compose files moved from /data/Dev/docker/compose to /mydocs/Dev/docker/compose.
$ cat /etc/docker/daemon.json 
{"data-root":"/mydocs/dockerdata"}

/mydocs/Dev/docker/compose$ ll
total 36K
lrwxrwxrwx 1 david david   33 Nov  7  2021 compose.yml -> ignition-8.1.11-postgres-14.0.yml
drwxrwxr-x 2 david david 4.0K Nov  5  2021 db-init
-rw-rw-r-- 1 david david 1.3K Oct 18 10:49 ignition-8.1.11-postgres-14.0.yml
-rw-rw-r-- 1 david david 1.5K Mar  5  2021 ignition-8.1.1-postgres-13.1.host.yml
-rw-rw-r-- 1 david david 1.3K Mar  7  2021 ignition-8.1.1-postgres-13.1.ports.yml
-rw-rw-r-- 1 david david 1.3K Mar  7  2021 ignition-8.1.1-postgres-13.1.yml
drwxrwxr-x 2 david david 4.0K Nov  5  2021 secrets

now when I try to run docker compose I get the following error. Where is the bind path set? because it's looking in the old location /data.
$ docker compose -f compose.yml start
[+] Running 0/0
 ⠋ Container compose_gateway_1  Starting                                                       0.0s 
 ⠋ Container compose_db_1       Starting                                                       0.0s 
Error response from daemon: invalid mount config for type "bind": bind source path does not exist: /data/Dev/docker/compose/secrets/GATEWAY_PASSWORD

My compose file:
# compose.yml
services:
  gateway:
    image: kcollins/ignition:8.1.11  # You can change `latest` to a specific version, e.g. `8.0.5`
    ports:
      - "8088:8088"
    stop_grace_period: 30s
    secrets:
      - gateway-password
    volumes:
      # - ./gateway_backup.gwbk:/restore.gwbk
      - gateway_data:/var/lib/ignition/data
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-size: "200k"
        max-file: "10"
    environment:
      GATEWAY_SYSTEM_NAME: DockerGW
      GATEWAY_ADMIN_USERNAME: david
      GATEWAY_ADMIN_PASSWORD_FILE: /run/secrets/gateway-password

  db:
    image: postgres:14.0
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
     - db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
     - ./db-init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-size: "200k"
        max-file: "10"
    secrets:
      - postgres-password
    environment:
      # See https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/ for more information
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD_FILE: /run/secrets/postgres-password
      POSTGRES_DB: ignition
      POSTGRES_USER: ignition

secrets:
  postgres-password:
    file: ./secrets/POSTGRES_PASSWORD
  gateway-password:
    file: ./secrets/GATEWAY_PASSWORD

volumes:
  gateway_data:
  db_data:

Docker version 27.3.1, build ce12230
Ubuntu 24.04LTS


I'd wonder if some of these paths are internally stored in the container metadata.  I think "secrets" are provided by Compose and not core Docker.  Does docker-compose down to delete the containers help at all?  Can your sysadmin delete the entire Docker data directory, and then you can restore the two data directories from backups, and start from a clean slate?

@DavidMaze I used docker-compose down then docker-compose up and now it's working. Thanks for the tip.

Can you check if you have any .env file
If so just update it with your newer path for example
COMPOSE_PROJECT_PATH=/mydocs/Dev/docker/compose 

There is no .env file
